# How to login into Google workspace using OIDC with my own identity provider

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, openid-connect, openid, google-workspace

I am building an SSO system for android where I am the identity provider. And I want users to sign in from my app that will automatically log them in to google workspace (or any other enterprise application e.g salesforce). I cannot figure out what and how to send identity values from my Idp to Google workspace.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done this way round. When a user signs in to your app she can't be automatically signed in to any other application. The options that you have are:

1. When a user signs in to your application you can ask Google for an access token. As part of your sign-in process, you can run an OAuth flow against Google Authorization Servers and ask for proper permissions. This will allow the user to additionally log in to their Google account, consent to release information to your app and you will then get an access token that will enable you to call Google's APIs. This way your users will have to log in twice (both to your app and to Google).
2. You can rely on Google to log users into your app. So, Google will be the OIDC Provider and your app will only be the client. People will log in to their Google account, and you will get an ID token in return. You can use the data from the ID token to create user accounts and sessions in your app.

In the first case, you will want to have a look at OAuth flows, like the [code](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-code-flow/) flow. In the latter, you will need OIDC flow, e.g. the [OIDC code flow](https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-code-flow/).